# Wi-Fi disabled when I install Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

```
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 60:d8:19:63:32:c6
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:c2500000-c250ffff
```

Output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the network key in your keyboard and press that or check in BIOS whether WLAN is enabled or not.